# How to get the running instances of PowerPoint in C++?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I want to populate a wxComboBox with the list of PPT Files(path) opened in the system.

How to do that?

Comment: COM to attach to a running instance, if there is more than one instance you will have to poke about in the ROT: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/196776

Comment: Assuming the PPT files are opened in PowerPoint/Office and not some other program that does not announce its open files to the ROT.